# SQLCommandType.View - why is not this provided by MS?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ado.net

We see that System.Data.CommandType has only 3 enums: "StoredProcedure", "TableDirect" and "Text". Why don't we see "View" as an option? What is the Framework specific reason Microsoft does not provide this option?

I am specifically talking about the SQL Server Views here.

Your answer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because a `View` is accessible via `TableDirect` or `Text`. The most common access is `Text` anyway because you're generally doing something like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cString))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, c))
    {
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("parm1", value1);

        c.Open();
        sda.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

Finally, a view is actually represented as a table in SQL Server. It has a real table definition, it just happens to be built with a query.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times View is not used by itself but rather as a part of a query or SP. Hence it's not necessary to provide a dedicated CommandType. Same thing goes for Functions - there's no CommandType.Function.